# Biblatex + Currvita for clever way of managing cv

Tags: biblatex, currvita

I'm trying to make a cv, based on the currvita package, because I like seeing the publication years neatly aligned to the left. However, I'd also like to use Biblatex to manage the references to the work.

What I've come up with so far is

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\usepackage[NoDate]{currvita}
\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{Curriculum Vitae}
    \begin{cvlist}{Publications}
    \item[1948] \citetitle{Quine:1948}
    \end{cvlist}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Which together with the bibfile, which I call mwe.bib

```
@article{Quine:1948,
Author = {Willard V. Quine},
Journal = {The Review of Metaphysics},
Month = {September},
Number = {5},
Pages = {21--38},
Title = {On What There Is},
Volume = {2},
Year = {1948}
}
```

will produce a nice looking output. The problem I have is that with the \citetitle command, Biblatex will really only produce the name of the publication. I had hoped to actually be able to reproduce the entire bibliographical information of the entry, except the year, which is already included in the nicely arranged labels in the \item[].

I am guessing that what I need to do is create a new citation command. I've had a look at section 3.7 of the Biblatex documentation, but I can't make sense of what I need to do to get a new citation command. Can anybody point me the right direction?

Let me ask about two further issues, just in case there are easy solutions that somebody can point me towards:

1. Is it possible to create a single command that would cite the paper
   and automagically enter the year into the \item[] bit? That
   would be really helpful.
2. It'd be really great if this could all work with hyperref as well, is that possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `\newcommand\citeitem[1]{\item[\citeyear{#1}] \cite{#1}}`?

Comment: that's neat, but then it doesn't display the title and journal information, it just gives a `[1]'

Comment: Replace `\cite` with whatever citation you want. Perhaps `\fullcite` or, as you have, `\citetitle`.

Comment: but if I do: \newcommand\citeitem[1]{\item[\citeyear{#1}] \citetitle{#1}} that gives me the title info back. that's helpful though. that solves one of my issues.

Comment: as for the second part, you're going to need to clarify what you mean be 'working with hyperref'. for one, whatever you're asking is 'possible', but it might already exist. do you want all references to the citation in the text to point to this info? or do you want the citation info to link out somewhere on the web? please explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24623/discussion-between-shane-and-sean-allred).

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, you can use

```
\newcommand\fancything[1]{\item[\citeyear{#1}] \fullcite{#1}}
```

You can replace `\fullcite` with whatever citation command you want.

For the second question, well, please ask a new question :) We like to keep things 'one post per question' to avoid a 'coupling' effect.